# Print a copy of my app in the iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, printing, ios-simulator

What's the quickest way to print a hardcopy (paper) of my app running in the iPhone Simulator?

Comment: Your question isn't exactly clear.  Do you want to take screenshots of your application running in the simulator?  Try Command+Shift+4 and then select the area of the iphone simulator you want to capture, the image will be saved to the desktop.  If this is not what you need please try to rephrase the question.

Comment: no need to be snippy, Eric was trying to help. A "hardcopy of an app" is not a clear statement, since you might be referring to a screenshot, or a printout of some data that's in the app, or something else.

Answer (score 5):

Command + Shift + 4 and then hit the space bar so you see a Camera for the cursor. Click on the Simulator window and voila. Then print it out.

Answer (score 5):

Open your app and go to the screen you want to capture.

In the menubar, click Edit.  Hold Control and you should see an option 'Copy Screen'.

Click that and then open Preview on your mac.  In the menubar go to File->New from clipboard.

From there you can print or save the image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an application like LittleSnapper or Acorn to capture the window, and then print directly from there. That's a lot quicker than having to manually select the bounds and you won't get any stuff in the background. But it will include the iPhone frame around the app, don't know if you want that.

Comment: I wanted:  Free... easy... quick.  (Don't care about "frame" or "no frame".)

Comment: You didn't say free in your original question. But looks like Steve's solution is the way to go, then.